# Run ubuntu without monitor in 12.10

Tags: monitor

HOW CAN I RUN MY UBUNTU 12.10 WITHOUT MONITOR ???? im trying to solve this problem 7 hours please help mee. xorg.conf cant help me. please tell me another solution. i will try everything..
thanks

Comment: Can you give us some more information?

Comment: Do you really run your Ubuntu without monitor? Simply unplug the monitor and allow Ubuntu to run. But if you are experiencing a graphics issue please provide enough details and the symptoms. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an ubuntu server. Those don't need a monitor attached for normal operation (though it certainly helps for initial setup).

For a better answer give more info on what would you like to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for response. I'd like to use my PC as server. I want to run it without monitor but it is not starting without it. I tried all solutions but still cant configure it. how to run my ubuntu Server vithout monitor plugged in and using teamviewer or vnc or anything? THANKS

Comment: You have installed ubuntu server right? And it does boot when you plug in your monitor normally right?